# Change values from Select Options Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to change the values from my select option input but can't figure out what seems to be the problem !
[image]

The selector is .woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations select {}

and here is my jquery code

```
    (function($) {
    console.log('couleur.js');
    // Target the select element using the CSS selector
    var selectElement = $('.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations select');
  
    // Define the new options
    var newOptions = {
        'White': 'Blanc',
        'Charcoal': 'Charbon',
        'Dark Heather': 'Gris foncé',
        'Dark Chocolate': 'Chocolat foncé',
        'Navy': 'Marine',
        'Black': 'Noir'
    };
    
    // Clear the existing options
    selectElement.empty();
    console.log('OPTIONS');

    // Add the new options
    $.each(newOptions, function(value, text) {
      selectElement.append($('<option></option>').val(value).html(text));
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not sure if i need to attach it to a certain woocommerce hook its and input from checkout fields